# Programmatically generating minimal QGIS map file (.qgs) containing specified PostGIS layers

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgs, specification

I am just wondering if there is a way to generate a QGIS map file (.qgs) from the list of data sources (PostGIS) that comprise the map.

I have many maps each containing two layers from a PostGIS database. So the maps are the same in structure. Currently, I create these map files manually, and track them using git. But it's cumbersome, and a save operation under a newer QGIS version can cause hundreds/thousands of lines of diff for each map.

Also, the QGIS map files are quite big, ranging from 20k to over 300k. All the essential information I need in each map is the names of the tables. (Randomly assigned default symbolization is OK for my purposes).

So, if I were to write a shell script (or program) to automate the map generating process, what is the **minimum** content that I need to write into a new .qgs to get a usable map?

Is there any template or documentation on the minimum required content of a .qgs map?

(I am using the latest QGIS, currently 3.20)

Comment: Couldn't you work this out by creating a) a .qgs file with no layers, and b) a qgs file starting from a) and adding one of your layers, then diffing a) and b). A .qgs file is an XML file so the only difference should be the XML for your layer. Adding further XML items for more layers should then create a QGS for all those layers.

Comment: You should be able to adapt https://github.com/Gustry/otf-project to achieve what you want